# Why would my Downloads folder become empty?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Why would most of my Downloads folder become empty? I suppose it was remiss of me to leave a lot of stuff in there, but I looked after downloading a few files last night and my Downloads folder was almost entirely gone. Just a few old files left. They're not in the wastebasket.

- Could another user have emptied this folder inadvertently from their Web Browser?
- Is it significant that I use the Chrono plugin for Chrome? (Other users of my PC might be using Internet Exploder).

Any suggestions to help prevent it happening again, or even recover it would be great. I read elsewhere on StackExchange of folks' Downloads moving to a different drive, but  I've searched my drives for "Podcasts" (a folder which I know existed in the Downloads folder. No joy.

Comment: Is your folder set up to sync?

Comment: @dave, I don't know what sync is. As indicated, I share the computer with other users, each of whom has their own local account. I don't share my account.

Comment: Two negative? I'd love to know who / why. The question is clear, demonstrates research effort, and could prove useful. Please believe me: "coming out" like this has been a last resort! I can work Google.

Comment: I think the down votes are unfair but are reflecting the question is possibly off topic,  not that it is a bad question. Anyway, most likely thing is either the AV has done some quarantining or some other use deleted them/moved them. Regardless I don't think we can answer this. This is obviously not normal behaviour and the fact that your own research showed nothing demonstrates that the question is not widely known nor easily replicable... As such it's too opinion based or too broad. Sorry ヽ(｀⌒´)ノ

Comment: I think you might be right. Couldn't load Windows Explorer in my profile today: the other local user accounts seemed fine. Never though of a chkdsk. Scheduled it from another account. Found a truckload of bad sectors. i think I'm going to flag this to be closed: as you say, it's properly out of scope.

Comment: Or you can answer your own question.  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was probably due to a number of bad sectors which had developed on the disk. it was fixed by scheduling a chkdsk from another (apparently working) local account. The sectors are now mark appropriately (I think) and the only side effect seems to have been the loss of the desktop preferences. The downloads folder wasn't recovered by this means.

A scan of the error logs reveals that the PC is being repeatedly depowered before shutdown is complete. My best guess is that one of our younger family members needs to be briefed.